$[F(a):F][F(b):F] \neq [F(a,b):F]$ for $F(a) \cap F(b)=F$

Given a field $F$, is it possible to find $a,b$ algebraic over $F$ such that $[F(a):F][F(b):F]\neq[F(a,b):F]$ and $F(a) \cap F(b)=F$?

If $\omega=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3})$, then $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$ has degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but what about $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\omega):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})]$?

How is your example related to your general question? (What are $a,b,F$ in it?)

I was looking for a counterexample and I'm not sure if that one would lead to such a counterexample

What are $a,b,F$ in this attempt?

A theorem states that if $F \subset F(a)$ is Galois,
$$[F(a):F][F(b):F] = [F(a,b):F]$$ is equivalent to $F = F(a) \cap F(b)$.
As both $\mathbb Q(\omega), \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ are Galois over $\mathbb Q$, you won't get a counterexample from those field extensions.
However, you can get one from $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are distinct roots of the polynomial $p(x) = x^3-2 \in \mathbb Q[x]$. You will be able to prove that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha): \mathbb Q] = [\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q]=3$ while $[\mathbb Q(\alpha, \beta): \mathbb Q] = 6$ and $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \cap \mathbb Q(\beta) = \mathbb Q$.
Note 1: this doesn't contradict the abovementioned theorem as the extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha), \mathbb Q(\beta)$ are not Galois over $\mathbb Q$.
Note 2: you can prove that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2},\omega):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})] = 2$, as $\omega \notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\omega$ is a root of $q(x) = x^2+x+1 \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)[x]$.
